# How to improve the performance for the SuperColumn query in cassandra?

Tags: performance, cassandra

I found cassandra use lots of cpu when query data which has SuperColumn in.
The call tree is

```
org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getColumnFamily
org.apache.cassandra.db.SuperColumnSerializer.deserialize
org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnSerializer.deserialize
```

detail to see [this article](http://hi.baidu.com/higkoo/blog/item/3d946a55adcaa8d2b645aeeb.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have a lot of subcolumns in the supercolumn; that's not what it's designed for. http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraLimitations

Comment: OK,Thanks a lot ! Add row key will improve this problem ;**nodetool -h localhost -p 8080 -u admin-pw higkoo setcachecapacity ks1 cf1 200000 200000**